# What is the value of this triple integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm working through a question and it says:

$$\int_{0}^{5}\int_{-z}^{z}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{z^2-y^2}}3xz~dxdydz=2500$$

Yet I cannot seem to get that answer so I'm wondering if this is a mistake?

Comment: Yeah I spotted the error thanks.

Comment: If you've figured out a question, please don't edit your post the way you have here. It will garner you negative votes.

Comment: @Eric, you can always delete your own question... no need to ask someone else to do it.

Comment: @TravisJ only registered user can delete hir own post. That's one of the benefit of being registered ( Ref: [Why should I register my account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44562/270742) )

Comment: @achillehui, thanks.  I was unaware of that.

Answer (score 3):

First one:
$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{z^{2}-y^{2}}}3xz dx = \frac{3}{2}z(z^{2}-y^{2})$$
Second one:
$$1/2\int_{-z}^{z}3z(z^{2}-y^{2})dy=1/2\int_{-z}^{z}3z^{3}-3zy^{2} dy=1/2\left[3z^{3}y-zy^{3}\right]^{z}_{-z}=3z^{4}-z^{4}=2z^{4}$$
Last one:
$$\int_{0}^{5}2z^{4}=\frac{2}{5}5^{5}=10*125=1250$$
Unless I've made a mistake!

Comment: $\int x dx = \frac{1}{2}x^2 + c$... you forgot the $\frac{1}{2}$ in a few places.

Comment: Thank you! If you put it into the first integral and pray to the gods of linearity then you get the (correct) answer of 1250